# Immortal PHP Session

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, session

I'm having some issues in destroying a session for a logout. When I destroy the session it keeps coming back.

The code I am using is as follows:

```
public function kill_login(){
    global $response;
    session_start();
    $response->message = "Current session" . json_encode($_SESSION);
    // Unset all of the session variables.
    unset($_SESSION);
    $_SESSION = array();
    if (ini_get("session.use_cookies")) {
        $params = session_get_cookie_params();
        setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 42000,
            $params["path"], $params["domain"],
            $params["secure"], $params["httponly"]
        );
    }
    session_destroy();
    session_write_close();
    
    $response->message .= "Session Destroyed" . json_encode($_SESSION);
}
```

It replies with below

[image: Returning Session]

This is called with ASync AJAX Request then reloads

```
$("<button>").text("Logout").click(function(){
    var logOut = {
        action:"logOut"
    };
    alert(SAJAX.getJSON(logOut,dataLoc).message);
    location.reload();
})
```

(SAJAX.getJSON is just a method that simplifies using AJAX for a standard request for mine, I use it a lot just fine)

The page then reloads and somehow the session is still there, I can click the logout button again and still get the same thing.

I only have `session_start()` used in three places: checking login (establishes session for the page), logon and killing a login since it is an AJAX request.

Any Ideas??

**Edit: I adjusted it to remove the second session_start() and add write_close same results.**

Comment: You started the session, then you destroyed it and then started it up again. There's the problem.

Comment: You're starting the session in the same page where you unset it.

Comment: Plus, you're only starting the session as soon as that function is called. Place `session_start();` as the first line, *n'est-ce pas?*

Comment: I only started the session to debug the values and show it is set to [].

Comment: Use `session_regenerate_id();` to get an new session id

Comment: Then before you run session_destroy, try `$_SESSION = array();` to remove all values.

Comment: You have 2 times `session_start()` ! One at the beginning and one at the end of your code

Comment: And use `session_write_close();` to kill the session data for real

Comment: Removing the second session_start() yields the same results. I added session_write_close() after session_destroy() same problem.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Many of the methods are sessionless as it's used to adjust user info from an admin side too.

Comment: I thing your problem is the *ajax call*. From PHP.net: `In order to kill the session altogether, like to log the user out, the session id must also be unset. If a cookie is used to propagate the session id (default behavior), then the session cookie must be deleted. setcookie() may be used for that.` and i thing your browser ajax call didnt change that for the browser cookie

Comment: At this point `location.reload()` the browser reloads the page with the old session id!

Comment: Oh, Lord, I just figured it out....... Apparently `location.reload()` Resents the POST data. Since I just arrived from the login page it was re-logging in each time I did a `location.reload()`. The session WAS dying, I was just making a new one each time. Changed to `window.location.href = "logon.php";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not in the PHP it is with the call to `location.reload();` which will resend the POST data. Since the page was immediately POSTed to by the log-in page the session was being destroyed by the log-out call then a new session was being created due to the POST to the page being resent initiating the login method.

Changing the `location.reload()` to `window.location.href = "logon.php";`resolves the issue since the page was no longer being sent the POST data.